# Ke vs. kiu: which one to use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between these two words? My dictionary mentions that both mean **that**, but how does one know which one to use? Can you please provide some examples? Dankon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Ke" connects a verb to a phrase:

- Mi ne sciis ke li studis en Londono.
- Mirigas min ke ili sukcesis
- Mi ĝojas ke la suno brilas.

"Kiu" connects a noun to a description:

- Mi ne antaŭe vidis la viron kiu staras tie.
- La knabino kiu grimpas la arbon estas mia filino.
- Ne parolu kun homojn kiujn vi ne konas.

"Kiu" can be replaced with "that" or "which".

Answer (score 7):

This is how I look at it.

*ke* joins two grammatically complete expressions, usually complete sentences, but it can include prepositional phrases, as in the first example.

- *Por konvinki tiun sinjoron, **ke** li eraras* - to convince this man **that** he is making a mistake.
- *mi efektive tute ne volus, **ke** li estu tiel fidela.* - In fact I would not want **that** he should be so faithful (I wouldn't want him to be so faithful)

The clauses are complete without *ke*, which is just a little bit of grammatical glue to stick them together.

- *Por konvinki tiun sinjoron*
- *li eraras*
- *Mi ne volus*
- *li estu tiel fidela*

On the other hand, *kiu* is actually part of the clause... it is acting or being acted on by the verb.

- *la rivereto, **kiu** antaŭe estis ruĝe kolorigita* - The stream **which** had previously been colored red.
- *La kampisto, **kiu** tie plugadis* - The peasant **who** had been plowing there.
- *en la mano, **kiu** ilin deŝiras* - In the hand **which** plucks them.

In every case, *kiu* isn't just gluing together two thoughts, it actually representes the *rivereto*, the *kampisto*, the *mano*.

Since *kiu* is actually part of the clause, it would take appropriate grammatical endings.

- *sceno, **kiun** la luno vidis* - a scene that the moon saw.

*Kiu* here represents the scene, and is receiving the action of *vidis* and so needs the -n ending.

Above examples are *Zamenhofaj* from *La batalo de l’ vivo*. Translations are mine.